# How would I best handle the next event when form validation fails?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a hidden form that is populated and shown in a wrapper when a user edits a record.  I have validation in place in the form's onChange event.  If the user clicks a button "done", the app cleans up the form and hides the wrapper.

Here's what I'm running into.  If the user enters invalid data into one of the inputs and clicks done, the done code is fired before the validation is complete.

What are some ways to avoid this?  I'm using prototypejs framework.

Here's the code for validation: (observing form "change"):

```
    // code
onFormChange: function (event, element) {
    /* uses updateField to:
        1.) determine if a new value has been given
        2.) validate new value
        3.) run additional functions on Update, after update and on failure
    */
    try {
        var classInst = this;
        // convert checkbox value to y / n
        var testVal = (element.type === "checkbox") ? (element.checked) ? "Y" : "N" : element.getValue();
        var field = this.items.edit.itemInEdit.fields[element.id];
        var updateOptions = {};
        // if qty, additional validation
        if (element.id == "qty") 
          updateOptions.onUpdate = function (qtyVal, element) { 
              return classInst.isQtyValid(qtyVal, element); 
          };
        // add afterUpdate which will update grouped fields and more.
        updateOptions.afterUpdate = function () { 
            classInst.afterUpdateField(field); 
        };
        // add onFailure of selecting element
        updateOptions.onFailure = function () { 
            element.select(); 
        };
        // call field's updateField
        field.updateField(testVal, updateOptions);
    } catch (err) {
        this.showMsg("Error editing form field - " + err);
    }
},
updateField: function (newVal, options) {
    try {
        /*
            Options can contain functions:
            1.  onUpdate fires after validation if isNewValue.  Must return true to continue updating field.
            1.  afterUpdate fires after successful update with new data.
            2.  onFailure fires if newVal fails validation.
        */
        var localOptions = {};
        this.updateObject(localOptions, options);
        // format value based on field type
        switch (this.type) {
            case "decimal":
                newVal = parseFloat(newVal).toMoney(this.numericScale, ".", "");
                break;
            case "int":
                // do nothing at the momemt
                break;
            case "char":
                // convert to upper case
                newVal = newVal.toUpperCase();
                break;
        };
        // compare new value to original value which is called current value
        if (this.name == "partNum") alert(newVal + ", " + this.originalValue);
        var isNewValue = (newVal != this.originalValue);
        // validate only if new value.
        var isValid = true;
        if (isNewValue)
            isValid = this.validator.validateFieldObject(newVal, this, localOptions.onFailure);

        // stop processing if new value is not valid.
        if (!isValid) return false;
        // run onUpdate function if exists before continuing.  This function can stop processing if necessary.
        var continueProcessing = true;
        if (isNewValue && localOptions.onUpdate) continueProcessing = localOptions.onUpdate(newVal);
        if (!continueProcessing) return false;
        // update field value with raw new value always because we could be setting back to original value after having changed it but before saving.
        this.value = newVal;
        // update cell value regardless of isNewValue.  In case I did some inline editing.
        if (this.cell) this.cell.update(newVal);
        // call afterUpdate.
        this.updateItemsChangeObject(this, isNewValue);
        // Lastly call after update if exists.
        if (localOptions.afterUpdate) localOptions.afterUpdate(isNewValue);
    } catch (err) {
        this.showMsg("Error updating field " + this.name + " - " + err);
    }
},
```

A separate onclick event on the wrapper (observing wrapper "click") for the "done" button:

```
// code
click: function (event) {
    /* an observer for any click events */
    var element = Event.findElement(event);
    switch (element.id) {
        case "doneEditButton":
            this.afterEditItem("done");
            break;
        case "addItem":
            this.createNewItem("I");
            this.contextMenu.hide();
            break;
        case "addCost":
            this.createNewItem("C");
            this.contextMenu.hide();
            break;
    };
},
afterEditItem: function (action) {
    // clean up
    this.items.edit.itemInEdit = null;
    this.items.edit.form.reset();
    this.items.edit.wrapper.hide();
},
```

Comment: Can you post your code? I imagine you are most likely trying to do something synchronous with asynchronous code.

Comment: Enable the show state of the form that is populated on the success of the validation. in such a way that it depends solely the validation's success.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @generalgmt.

Comment: I've added onfocus event to each of the forms elements which sets an attribute called editing to true.  Once onFormChange is complete, it sets the value to false.  On the click event I test the editing value.  If true, I stop processing.  This works but feels like a hack.  What are some other techniques I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I've added onfocus event to each of the forms elements which sets an attribute called editing to true. Once onFormChange is complete, it sets the value to false. On the click event I test the editing value. If true, I stop processing. This works but feels like a hack.